# Using toolz.pipe with methods

Tags: python, pipe, pipeline, toolz

I have a string that I want to clean using [`pipe`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.pipe) from toolz. But it seems I can't figure out how to apply the `str.replace` method in the pipeline. Here is an example:

```
x = '9\xa0766'

from toolz import pipe
import unidecode

# Can do like this, but don't want to use nesting.
int(unidecode.unidecode(x).replace(" ", ""))


# Wan't to try to do like this, with sequence of steps, applying transformations on previous output.
pipe(x, 
  unidecode.unidecode, 
  replace(" ", ""), 
  int
) # DON'T WORK!! 
# NameError: name 'replace' is not defined
```

More generally, notice that the output of `unidecode.unidecode` is a string. So I want to be able to apply some string methods to it.

```
pipe(x, 
  unidecode.unidecode, 
  type
)  # str
```

Is it possible with pipe?

Comment: `replace` isn't a *function*, you'd need e.g. `lambda s: s.replace(...)` or maybe a `partial`.

Comment: Thank you for that. `Lambda` is good :). Can you please give an example how would I use `partial` here?? Thank you :) @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the same in slightly different way using lambda

```
import unidecode
from toolz import pipe

x = '9\xa0766'


pipe(
    x,
    unidecode.unidecode,
    lambda x: x.replace(" ", ""),
    int
)
```

You could also make it into a function to reuse it elsewhere

```
import unidecode
from toolz import pipe, compose_left

x = '9\xa0766'

# this becomes a function that can be called
converter = compose_left(
    unidecode.unidecode,
    lambda x: x.replace(" ", ""),
    int
)


result = converter(x)

print(result)
#9766
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with `toolz.pipe`.  Although you can use a lambda, I would use `operator.methodcaller` as so:

```py
import operator as op
import unidecode
from toolz import pipe

x = '9\xa0766'

# Can do like this, but don't want to use nesting.
int(unidecode.unidecode(x).replace(" ", ""))

# Wan't to try to do like this, with sequence of steps, applying transformations on previous output.
pipe(
    x,
    unidecode.unidecode,
    op.methodcaller("replace", " ", ""),
    int
)
```